# Should Storyboard References work with Container Views?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I just tried it out and it doesn't seem to work, see picture. However, there is error or warning, and since a reference is a view controller - should it be possible?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have an initial view controller set in the referenced storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up a parent/child relationship with a container view is easy.Just create a container view inside the parent `ViewController`, create the child view controller scene, and then control-drag from the container view to the child view controller to create the `embed` segue.

If you want to swap the child view controllers depending on some condition, i.e. multiple child view controllers, just create a custom segue. This custom segue is named Empty and is a subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue` with empty `perform` method.

Comment: To clarify a bit - Make sure your storyboard reference is configured to point to your second storyboard and to the desired controller by storyboard ID (use the attributes inspector).  Then as said above control-drag from the container to the storyboard ref and choose "embed" as the type.  The segue will move from the default placeholder VC to your storyboard ref and you can delete the unused one.